# Correct way to expand the generating functional

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, perturbation-theory, propagator

Consider the following self-interacting real scalar field theory
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)(\partial^\mu\phi) - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2 - \frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4
$$
with $m^2 > 0$ and $\lambda > 0$. It is well-known that the generating functional of the full (i.e., interacting) theory can be written as
$$
Z[J] = \exp\Biggl\{-i\frac{\lambda}{4!} \int dx\ \frac{\delta^4}{\delta J(x)^4}\Biggr\}Z_0[J]
$$
where
$$
Z_0[J] = \mathcal{N} \exp\Biggl\{-\frac{1}{2} \int dz \int dw\ J(z) \Delta_F(z - w) J(w)\Biggr\}
$$
is the generating functional of the corresponding free theory. Here
$$
\Delta_F(z - w) = \int \frac{dp}{(2\pi)^d}\ \frac{i}{p^2 - m^2} e^{ip(z - w)}
$$
is Feynman's propagator of the scalar field $\phi$ and $\mathcal{N}$ is a normalization constant.

We can expand -in powers of $\lambda$- the exponential operator
$$
\exp\Biggl\{-i\frac{\lambda}{4!} \int dx\ \frac{\delta^4}{\delta J(x)^4}\Biggr\} = \sum^\infty_{\ell=0} \frac{(-i)^\ell \lambda^\ell}{(4!)^\ell\ell!} \int dx_1 \cdots \int dx_\ell\ \frac{\delta^{4\ell}}{\delta J(x_1)^4 \cdots \delta J(x_\ell)^4}.
$$
On the other hand, my problem is that:

> I am not sure how to make a series expansion of the generating functional $Z_0[J]$ of the free theory.

I see two possibilities:

1. According to equation (1.49) from [this](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/FabianEssler/C6web2012/theory/quantumpath.pdf) document (here, the author is working with the $\phi^3$-real scalar theory and the generating functional is called $W[J]$ instead of $Z[J]$), I should be able to make the expansion
   \begin{align}
   Z_0[J] &= \mathcal{N} \exp\Biggl\{-\frac{1}{2} \int dz \int dw\ J(z) \Delta_F(z - w) J(w)\Biggr\} \\
   &= \mathcal{N} \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} \Biggl(-\frac{1}{2} \int dz \int dw\ J(z) \Delta_F(z - w) J(w)\Biggr)^k \\
   &= \mathcal{N} \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^k}{2^kk!} \int dz_1 \int dw_1 \cdots \int dz_k \int dw_k\ J(z_1)J(w_1) \cdots J(z_k)J(w_k) \Delta_F(z_1 - w_1) \cdots \Delta_F(z_k - w_k).
   \end{align}
   If this is correct, then we would have the functional expansion
   \begin{align}
   Z[J] &= \mathcal{N} \sum^\infty_{\ell=0} \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^k(-i)^\ell \lambda^\ell}{(4!)^\ell\ell!2^kk!} \int dx_1 \cdots \int dx_\ell\  \int dz_1 \int dw_1 \cdots \int dz_k \int dw_k \\
   &\quad \times \Delta_F(z_1 - w_1) \cdots \Delta_F(z_k - w_k) \frac{\delta^{4\ell}}{\delta J(x_1)^4 \cdots \delta J(x_\ell)^4} J(z_1)J(w_1) \cdots J(z_k)J(w_k).
   \end{align}
   Consequently, some lowest-order terms are
   \begin{align}
   \frac{Z[J]}{\mathcal{N}} &= \lambda^0\Biggl\{1 - \frac{1}{2} \int dz_1 \int dw_1\ \Delta_F(z_1 - w_1)J(z_1)J(w_1) + \cdots\Biggr\} \\
   &\quad + \lambda\Biggl\{- \frac{i}{8} \int dx_1\ \Delta_F(x_1 - x_1)\Delta_F(x_1 - x_1) + \cdots\Biggr\} + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2).
   \end{align}
2. According to equation (92) from [this](https://sanjeev.seahra.ca/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/path_integrals.pdf) document, the correct series expansion of $Z_0[J]$ is given by a Volterra series
   \begin{align}
   Z_0[J] &= \mathcal{N} \exp\Biggl\{-\frac{1}{2} \int dz \int dw\ J(z) \Delta_F(z - w) J(w)\Biggr\} \\
   &= \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} \int dz_1 \cdots \int dz_k\ J(z_1) \cdots \delta J(z_k) \frac{\delta^kZ_0[J]}{\delta J(z_1) \cdots \delta J(z_k)}\Biggr|_{J=0}.\end{align}
   If this is correct, then we would have the functional expansion
   \begin{align}
   Z[J] &= \sum^\infty_{\ell=0} \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-i)^\ell \lambda^\ell}{(4!)^\ell\ell!k!} \int dx_1 \cdots \int dx_\ell\  \int dz_1 \cdots \int dz_k \\
   &\quad \times \Biggl[\frac{\delta^{4\ell}}{\delta J(x_1)^4 \cdots \delta J(x_\ell)^4} J(z_1) \cdots J(z_k)\Biggr] \frac{\delta^kZ_0[J]}{\delta J(z_1) \cdots \delta J(z_k)}\Biggr|_{J=0}.
   \end{align}
   Consequently, some lowest-order terms are
   \begin{align}
   \frac{Z[J]}{\mathcal{N}} &= \lambda^0\Biggl\{1 - \frac{1}{2} \int dz_1 \int dz_2\ J(z_1)J(z_1)\Delta_F(z_1 - z_2) \\
   &\quad - \frac{1}{4!}\int dz_1 \int dz_2 \int dz_3 \int dz_4\ J(z_1)J(z_2)J(z_3)J(z_4) \\
   &\quad \times \Bigl[\Delta_F(z_1 - z_2)\Delta_F(z_3 - z_4) + \Delta_F(z_1 - z_3)\Delta_F(z_2 - z_4) + \Delta_F(z_1 - z_4)\Delta_F(z_2 - z_3)\Bigr] + \cdots\Biggr\} \\
   &\quad + \lambda\Biggl\{\cdots\Biggr\} + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2).
   \end{align}
   Thus, as far as I can see both expansion are not yielding the same result. I would like to know which one is the correct one and why is the other wrong; or maybe both are equivalent but I can't see it.

EDIT: if both expansion for the generating functional $Z_0[J]$ are equal, i.e.
$$
\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} \int dz_1 \cdots \int dz_k\ J(z_1) \cdots \delta J(z_k) \frac{\delta^kZ_0[J]}{\delta J(z_1) \cdots \delta J(z_k)}\Biggr|_{J=0} = \mathcal{N} \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^k}{2^kk!} \int dz_1 \int dw_1 \cdots \int dz_k \int dw_k\ J(z_1)J(w_1) \cdots J(z_k)J(w_k) \Delta_F(z_1 - w_1) \cdots \Delta_F(z_k - w_k)
$$
then, could we set the following identification?
$$
\frac{\delta^kZ_0[J]}{\delta J(z_1) \cdots \delta J(z_k)}\Biggr|_{J=0} = \mathcal{N} \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} \int dw_1 \cdots \int dw_k\ J(w_1) \cdots J(w_k) \Delta_F(z_1 - w_1) \cdots \Delta_F(z_k - w_k)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two series for $Z_0[J]$ are equivalent. This generating functional is defined by :
\begin{align}
Z_0[J] &= \mathcal{N} \exp\Biggl\{-\frac{1}{2} \int dz \int dw\ J(z) \Delta_F(z - w) J(w)\Biggr\} \\
&= \mathcal{N} \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} \Biggl(-\frac{1}{2} \int dz \int dw\ J(z) \Delta_F(z - w) J(w)\Biggr)^k \\
\end{align}
Then, the second series expansion is Taylor's formula :
\begin{align}
Z_0[J]&= \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} \int dz_1 \cdots \int dz_k\ J(z_1) \cdots J(z_k) \frac{\delta^kZ_0[J]}{\delta J(z_1) \cdots \delta J(z_k)}\Biggr|_{J=0}\end{align}

This formula actually holds for any functional $F[J]$ (which admits a formal series expansion) :

> \begin{align}
> F[J]&= \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} \int dz_1 \cdots \int dz_k\ J(z_1) \cdots J(z_k) \frac{\delta^kF[J]}{\delta J(z_1) \cdots \delta J(z_k)}\Biggr|_{J=0}\end{align}

To prove Taylor's formula, we assume that we can expand $F$ as :
$$ F[J]  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int dz_1\ldots\int dz_kF_k(z_1,\ldots,z_k)J(z_1)\ldots J(z_k)$$

where the $F_k$ are integral kernels. The calculations should work even if the $F_k$ are higher order distributions, but this is not needed here.

Then, we compute its $k$th functional derivative at $J = 0$. This vanishes except on the term which contains exactly $k$ insertions of $J$. Therefore :
$$\left.\frac{\delta^k F[J]}{\delta J(z_1)\ldots \delta J(z_k)}\right|_{J=0} = \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_k}F_k(z_{\sigma(1)},\ldots z_{\sigma(k)})$$
where the sum runs over all permutation of $\{1,\ldots,k\}$. When we integrate over $z_1,\ldots,z_k$, we can relabel the variables :
\begin{align}
 \int dz_1 \cdots \int dz_k\ J(z_1) \cdots J(z_k) \frac{\delta^kF[J]}{\delta J(z_1) \cdots \delta J(z_k)}\Biggr|_{J=0} &=\sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_k}\int dz_1 \cdots \int dz_k\ J(z_1) \cdots J(z_k)F_k(z_{\sigma(1)},\ldots z_{\sigma(k)}) \\
&= k! \int dz_1\ldots\int dz_kF_k(z_1,\ldots,z_k)J(z_1)\ldots J(z_k)
\end{align}
Dividing by $k!$ and summing over $k$, we see that Taylor's formula holds.

**NB** : the same calculations would have worked directly on $Z_0[J]$ but the precise expression for the kernels $F_k(z_1,\ldots,z_k)$ is hard to write down formally (Wick's theorem). Since it's precise form is not needed, it is easier to do the proof in a more general setting.

**Edit** : The expression for the functional derivatives of the free generating functional are given, for $n$ an even integer, by :
\begin{gather}
\left.\frac{\delta^{n} Z_0[J]}{\delta J(z_1) \ldots \delta J(z_{n})}\right|_{J=0} &= \left(-\frac 12\right)^n\sum_{\sigma \in\mathfrak S_{n}} \Delta_F(z_{\sigma(1)}-z_{\sigma(2)})\ldots \Delta_F(z_{\sigma(n-1)} -z_{\sigma(n)})
\end{gather}
For $n$ odd, the functional derivative vanishes.

Comment: I understood your steps but unfortunately the only thing I see is a derivation of the Volterra series for $Z_0[J]$, i.e., how the kernels $F_k$ are related to de functional derivatives at $J=0$. I still can't see how the two series expansions of $Z_0[J]$ are equal. If this is true (which I'm also inclined to think so), then shouldn't we able to make the identification that I made in the edit of the question?

Comment: The equation in your edit cannot be true, since it contains some $J$ insertions in the RHS, which are set to zero. I edited in the correct formula.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I thought I was comparing coefficients of series, but now I see I'm comparing two integrands which, of course, are not necessarily equal, i.e., $\int dx\  f(x) = \int dx\ g(x)\ \nRightarrow\ f(x) = g(x)$. Also, from your edit (Wick theorem) I was able to see that, after a change of variables, the Volterra series of $Z_0$ will reduce to its Taylor series. Thanks for your help!